# Re import updated variable

Tags: javascript

For an example say I've two files a.js and b.js

a.js

```
const obj = {a: "a"}

function updateA() {
  obj.a = "b"
}

exports.A = obj.a
```

b.js

```
const {A} = require("a.js")

console.log(A) //prints a
```

Now when I called `updateA()` obj.a value changes but still b.js still prints A value as "a".
How to get the updated value in b.js?

Comment: Export a `getA` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic reference vs value example. When you do `exports.A = obj.a`, you're exporting the string "a", not a reference to `obj.a`. In order to get the updated value, you need to export a reference to `obj` instead:

a.js

```
const obj = {a: "a"}

function updateA() {
  obj.a = "b"
}

exports.A = obj;
```

b.js

```
const { A } = require("a.js")

console.log(A.a) //prints b
```

Comment: A couple of things here: 1. Technically, you could use `Object.defineProperty` on exports, to export a get accessory. 2. You removed the object destructuring `const {A} = require("a.js")` in order to make this work, that's necessary and you should call it out